# Error when assigning auto-created label to threads (TypeError: thread[t].addLabel is not a function) - google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, label

I'm trying to assign auto-created label to gmail threads. The label alone was successfully created but it couldn't be assigned to the respective threads due to a TypeError.

Here's the script

```
//call cell value by column (Sheet: "SupplierNumber")
//label created based on the "Label" column in Sheet: SupplierNumber
//Label applied to related threads

function callLabelcolumn() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('SupplierNumber');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A2:A');
  var vA=rg.getValues();

  var sh3 = ss.getSheetByName("SearchParameter")
  var rg3=sh3.getRange('A2');
  var searchPara =rg3.getValues();  

  var threads = GmailApp.search(searchPara);
  
          
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++){
    var msg = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < msg.length; j++){
            
      // Get same thread by its ID.
      //var threadID = GmailApp.getThreadById(msg[j].getId());
      var msgid = msg[j].getId();
      } 
  }


  vA.forEach(function(row) {
  if(row != "" && row != "#N/A"){
   
   Logger.log('Label: %s', row);
    var label = GmailApp.createLabel(row);
    
   Logger.log("label: " + label);
             
   }  
     
    var thread = [0];
    var thread = GmailApp.getMessageById(msgid).getThread().getId();
    var name = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label.getName())

     for(var t in thread){
    console.log("So far so good. Let's add label")
    thread[t].addLabel(name);
      }
  

  });

   
}
```

The error is " TypeError: thread[t].addLabel is not a function " when run script in the editor.
[TypeError: thread[t].addLabel is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c41ux.png)

After debugging, I'm suspecting var name returned "" or null which is why the error is happening.

[Debug result: thread[t].addLabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcKB2.png)

I tried debugging on var name, some of results were name: undefined, t: undefined which I think is the cause of the TypeError.

[Debug result: var name = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label.getName())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB2jy.png)

So is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem lies in the line

`var thread = GmailApp.getMessageById(msgid).getThread().getId();`

### The method [addLabel()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#addlabellabel) needs to be applied on the thread resource rather than a threadId.

A working code snippet would be:

```js
    var thread = GmailApp.getMessageById(msgid).getThread();
    var name = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label.getName())
    console.log("So far so good. Let's add label")
    thread[t].addLabel(name);
```

Other wissue in your code are:

- You are trying to loop through `thread`, but in your case `thread` is not array, but a single value
- You retrieve the `msgid` within a lopo and overwrite it within each iteration, however you use `msgid` for retrieving the thread only after exiting the loop - this means only for the very last value of `msgid`.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much. That solves the TypeError. I've also considered the issue you point out about `msgid` and moved the code for create label and addlabel() into the for loop with `msgid`. It's working, but the labels were assigned to every email threads instead of just one respective thread. What do you think is the solution for this? Should I post it as another question?

Comment: Hi Anies! Yes, according to the Stackoverflow guidelines you should post it as a new question with your updated code.

Comment: Hi ziganotschka! I've posted a new question with the updated code, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67981458/assigning-auto-created-gmail-labels-to-respective-threads-google-apps-script?answertab=active#tab-top). You can take a look at it if you're interested. Thanks again!